# Filter Category Loop Dynamically

Tags: categories, loop

I'm trying to display a custom loop with a dynamic category filter.

As a setup I have categories of all usernames which are created once a user creates an account.

So I am trying to echo the user's username as a category filter. It works when I echo is elsewhere on the page, but it doesn't work when I try to embed it like so:

```
<?php query_posts('category_name=<?php global $current_user; if ( isset($current_user) ) {echo $current_user->user_login;}?> &posts_per_page=6'); ?>

<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>  
<?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?> by <?php the_author_posts_link() ?>

<?php endwhile; else: ?>

NO Posts Present 

<?php endif; ?>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are opening a php tag inside an open php tag so you are actually calling this whole string:
`<?php global $current_user; if ( isset($current_user) ) {echo $current_user->user_login;}?>` as a category and you echo it out (wrongly) which is not passing ia as a perameter to `query_posts` move it outside the `query_posts` call:

```
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
query_posts(array('category_name' => $current_user->user_login,'posts_per_page'=>6));
```

I Would recommend catching up on basic PHP before moving on, and once you got that part down then you should avoid using `query_posts` altogether and use either `get_posts()`  or `wp_query` [read up on it](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts)